# GitLab CI Regex not running job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus

I'm having an issue where Gitlab-CI will not run my job no matter what I try. I am using a regex expression to match with a variable I have defined within my pipeline (It's read from a file via python script), the echo shows the variable is defined, however the regex is not matching.

I am looking for 'dev' anywhere within the variable. If this is the case, it should run the build job. A snippet of the gitlab-ci.yml file is below:

```
before_script:
  - "docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY"
  - "echo $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  - NEW_TAG=$(python3 read_current_version.py)   
  - export NEW_TAG=$(python3 read_current_version.py)
  - "echo $NEW_TAG"

build:
  stage: "build"
  tags: 
    - "shell"
  script:
    - "cd ./app"
    - "echo BUILDING $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FLASK:$NEW_TAG"
    - "docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FLASK:$NEW_TAG -f ./Dockerfile ."
    - "echo PUSHING $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FLASK:$NEW_TAG"
    - "docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FLASK:$NEW_TAG"
  rules:
    - if: $NEW_TAG =~ /dev/
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

I expected the job to run when a new commit is pushed, however it doesn't run and is skipped meaning that the match case isn't matched.

Answer (score 0):

Your `build` job is not being executed, because when GitLab is evaluating the condition that you've set up on your `rules`, the variable is empty. Even if you're using a global `before_script`, this will run as part of the `build` job but right before the `script`.

That part of the code will never be executed because GitLab decides to add the job to the pipeline based on your `rules` condition, and at that point in time the variable `$NEW_TAG` is empty.

To overcome that, you can create a dummy job that runs before `build` and generates the variable so then you pass it to this job via an artifact. [Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job) you have an example from the docs on how to do so.

Another option would be using downstream pipelines but I think that would be too much of an effort for your use-case.

Comment: I've tried this but no luck. The next job can see the tag using build.env but still doesn't match the regex pattern...

```$echo BUILDING $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE_FLASK:$NEW_TAG
BUILDING flask-backend:0.1.7-dev0```

Comment: That's strange, I'd expect GitLab to be capable of making use of that variable for the `rules` key if it's available on the job later on. The regex shouldn't be an issue as it's a simple check, so I wonder if this is something not behaving as expected from GitLab. Perhaps worth opening an issue with them?